# how to remove bottom line and arrow in material spinner

Tags: android

I donot want the spinner dropdown arrow and bottom line, I have tried following things in xml

```
  <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:dropDownSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: You need to override `fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner` class to create your own `CustomMaterialSpinner` class to make changes you want, as library does not have inbuilt methods to do that. And then use your `CustomMaterialSpinner` class in your `xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code...

```
 <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:ms_alignLabels="false"
    app:ms_arrowColor="#00ff16b1"
    app:ms_arrowSize="0dp"
    app:ms_enableErrorLabel="false"
    app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="false"
    app:ms_floatingLabelText="floating label"
    app:ms_hint="hint"
    app:ms_multiline="false"
    app:ms_thickness="0dp"
    />
```

make the ms_thickness 0dp and ms_arrowcolor transparent(add 00 prefix in any hex color code make the color transparent)

Comment: how to change material spinner height i want height as 50dp,but if i do so the text, are you having any idea? @Pawanpreet

Answer (score 1):

we can use

```
app:ms_basecolor="@android:color/transparent"
app:ms_hightlightcolor="@android:color/transparent"
```

this will remove both the arrow and line.Where as that highlight color when we click on spinner wont appear.If we still want arrow than just add

```
app:ms_arrowcolor="@color/black"
```